# Are percentage bonuses one off or on going?

Tags: civilization-5

When I build a wonder that gives a percentage bonus, for example Hagia Sophia gives +33% generation of great people, is that percentage bonus applied once to the current base generation rate or it is on-going? i.e. if the base great person generation rate increases, is this bonus re-applyed to this rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All percentage bonuses are live and recalculated whenever the affected value changes**, which is to say they are always based on the *current* base value, and not any historical value.

Since it's the given example, lets look at the +33% bonus to great person generation from the Hagia Sohpia.

Let's say that initially you have a city producing +3 great engineer points, with no other percentage effects currently in place.
You then build the Hagia Sohpia.
The +33% from the wonder will be applied to +3, boosting the output to +4.

Then, a few turns later, you adjust the citizen allocations for this city so that the base rate is now +6.
The +33% from the wonder will be applied to +6 (the *current* value), boosting the output to +8.

Comment: I just want to add that percentage bonuses are rounded not in your favour. That is 4+33%=5 and even 5+33%=6.

Answer (score 2):

Most percentage based bonuses in the game are applied *last*. This means that if you are currently generating 3 great engineer points per turn and you build the Hagia Sophia, your new "gpp" looks like this

```
Engineer 4 (3 + 1: 3 base, 1 +33% Hagia Sophia)
Artist 0 (0 + 0: 0 base, 0 +33% Hagia Sophia)
Merchant 0 (0 + 0: 0 base, 0 +33% Hagia Sophia)
Scientist 0 (0 + 0: 0 base, 0 +33% Hagia Sophia)
```

This works the same way for any other city % modifier, such as the forge, workshop, windmills, etc. Percentage bonuses are applied *last*.